# share the session between rails and php for checking if the user is authenticated?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-variables

I have a `ruby on rails` application and now i have to include a `php` app along this with the single `sign in`. I want to `login` and pass the `session` value to the php code so that it can check if the user is `authenticated`. But i do not know how to access the session that is passed from rails app in php? please help me.

Or tell me if i can use some other way to check if the user is authenticated in php from rails app. I am struggling with this for quiet a few hours. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you maintaining your sessions in the database?

Comment: no i am not maintaining.

Comment: i guess you can put some value to cookie, and write it to users table(and remove when user inactive for ex. for 1h or, after sign out), and then in your php app search in users table by cookie value